# Creating a gravity-like effect in CSS falling animation and calculating change of radius of a 'circle' when using rotateX

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

I have the following animation of a ball falling down and bouncing back up:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.ball {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  
  margin: 0 auto;
  
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  
  animation: bounce 2s infinite linear;
}

.ground {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
}

@keyframes bounce {
  0%,100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  
  20% {
    background-color: black;
    transform: translateY(40px);
  }
  
  50% {
    background-color: red;
    transform: translateY(84px) rotateX(45deg);
  }
  70% {
    background-color: black;
    transform: translateY(40px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class = "ball">
</div>

<div class = "ground">
</div>
```

As you can see, I tried to make the ball have a "squeezed" effect when it touches the ground. I had to use the `translateX` to `84px` to maintain the touching of the ball with the ground. I got that `84px` by trial and error. Is there a formula which I can use to calculate the offset (i.e. `4px` in this case)?

The ball is falling at a linear speed, I've tried using `ease-in` and `ease` and it didn't work. I've also tried different numbers from [cubic-bezier.com](http://cubic-bezier.com). How do I make it so that the velocity increases along with time because of gravitational acceleration and deceleration when it is bouncing back up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sup>*Check solution below if you hate maths **1***</sup>

Since you are rotating the element `45deg` you are having something like this:

[image]

What you are looking for is the Green line which you can get with the following formula:

```
width/2 - X
```

Where

```
X = Width/2*cos(45deg)
```

so you will have `Width/2*(1 - cos(45deg)) ~ Width/2*(1 - 0.707)`

You can then adjust the percentage value to control velocity. As a side note, you should not get to initial value but a lower value to have a more realistic animation:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.ball {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  
  margin: 0 auto;
  
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  
  animation: bounce 2s infinite ease-in;
}

.ground {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
}

@keyframes bounce {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  
  30% {
    background-color: black;
    transform: translateY(80px);
  }
  
  40% {
    background-color: red;
    transform: translateY(calc(80px + 10px*(1 - 0.707))) rotateX(45deg);
  }
  
  50% {
    background-color: black;
    transform: translateY(80px);
  }
  100% {
    background-color: black;
    transform: translateY(50px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class = "ball">
</div>

<div class = "ground">
</div>
```

<sup>**1**</sup> You can also avoid the calculation by simply changing the `transform-origin` to rotate from the bottom thus the space will be reduced from the top:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.ball {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  
  margin: 0 auto;
  
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  
  animation: bounce 2s infinite linear;
  transform-origin:bottom;
}

.ground {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
}

@keyframes bounce {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  
  30% {
    background-color: black;
    transform: translateY(78px);
  }
  
  40% {
    background-color: red;
    transform: translateY(80px) rotateX(45deg);
  }
  
  50% {
    background-color: black;
    transform: translateY(78px);
  }
  100% {
    background-color: black;
    transform: translateY(50px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class = "ball">
</div>

<div class = "ground">
</div>
```

If you want to have a non-realistic bounce effect you can try this:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.ball {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  
  margin: 0 auto;
  
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  
  animation: bounce 2s infinite linear;
  transform-origin:bottom;
}

.ground {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
}

@keyframes bounce {
  0%,100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  
  35%,65% {
    background-color: black;
    transform: translateY(40px);
  }
  
  45%,55% {
    background-color: black;
    transform: translateY(75px);
  }
  
  50% {
    background-color: red;
    transform: translateY(80px) rotateX(45deg);
  }


}
```

```html
<div class = "ball">
</div>

<div class = "ground">
</div>
```

Comment: It worked, how did you get the `width / 2 * cos(rotated_angle)` formula?

Comment: @WealthyPlayer I have also adjusted the keyframes

Comment: Hm correct me if I'm wrong, but it should be lower than its initial position because of energy loss right (the sound, heat etc.)? I'm still trying to figure out how to work the math out with trigonometry xD OH I GOT IT

Comment: I should take a break I think, I can't believe it took me 5 mins to figure out that simple computation xD It's `cosinus(45deg) = X / 10`, right?Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @WealthyPlayer yes, I have added more details ;) and also another way without calculation

Comment: Wow that's even better. Thank you! As for the gravitational effect, I still find it a little awkward. What if we ignore energy loss and assume that said ball can bounce repeatedly to the same height it fell from forever? `ease-in` wouldn't work, right?

Comment: @WealthyPlayer in this case everything should be linear but you make the changement to be faster when your reach the 50% ... so at 40% we are already at the half

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187457/discussion-between-wealthy-player-and-temani-afif).